# How to update input[type="range"] "value" attribute on clicking a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on custom range slider for my website. Everything is working fine but I am stuck in to make it possible that on clicking specific box slider(input[type="range"]) gets updated according to the data-label value of that specific div, so that we do not have to drag slider's thumb to update the custom bar? .Attached is the source code, Where I had Shared what I had achieved so far and What is left, For the convivence I had set opacity of range input to 0.1 so you can get the idea of what's going backend. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector('#customProgress');

for(let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min ; i++){
  const step = document.createElement('div');
  step.classList.add('step');
  step.setAttribute('data-label', +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
  customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`)
.classList.add('current')

function rangeScript(value){ 
  const target = document.getElementById('progress'); 
  
  let newValue = parseInt(this.value);
  const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
  if (currentStep) {
    currentStep.classList.remove('current');
  }
  

nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);

if (nextStep) {
  nextStep.classList.add('current')

}

}
```

```css
#customProgress {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
background: transparent;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.step::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  right: -.25em;
}

.step ~ .current,
.step.current {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>what I have achieved</h1>
<div id="customProgress">
  
</div> 
<div id="progress" style=" width: 100%;" > 
<input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 50px" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to add an event listener to the `step` divs. It 'hears' a click, get's it's own value from the `data-label` dataset, applies that value to the range element, then finally triggers the `rangeScript` event handler. The `rangeScript` handler needed to be adjusted to work with `event` (e). Event listeners pass one argument in their functions, `event` and the element that triggered the listener is always `event.target`.

```
step.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let val = e.target.dataset.label;
    document.querySelector('#price_slider').value = val
    rangeScript({target: rangeSlider}) // trigger the event using an adhoc representation of the rangeSlider event object
  })
```

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector('#customProgress');

for (let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min; i++) {
  const step = document.createElement('div');
  step.classList.add('step');
  step.setAttribute('data-label', +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
  step.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let val = e.target.dataset.label;
    document.querySelector('#price_slider').value = val
    rangeScript({
      target: rangeSlider
    })
  })
  customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`)
  .classList.add('current')

function rangeScript(e) {
  const target = document.getElementById('progress');
  let newValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
  const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
  if (currentStep) {
    currentStep.classList.remove('current');
  }
  nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);
  if (nextStep) {
    nextStep.classList.add('current')
  }
}
```

```css
#customProgress {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: transparent;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.step::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  right: -.25em;
}

.step~.current,
.step.current {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>what I have achieved</h1>
<div id="customProgress">

</div>
<div id="progress" style=" width: 100%;">
  <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 50px" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! you just explained the solution to the problem really well! Highly appreiciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using method `forEach()`.

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector("#price_slider");
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector("#customProgress");

for (let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min; i++) {
    const step = document.createElement("div");
    step.classList.add("step");
    step.setAttribute("data-label", +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
    customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`).classList.add("current");

function rangeScript(value) {
    const target = document.getElementById("progress");

    let newValue = parseInt(this.value);
    const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
    if (currentStep) {
        currentStep.classList.remove("current");
    }

    nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);

    if (nextStep) {
        nextStep.classList.add("current");
    }
}

const sections = document.querySelectorAll("#customProgress .step");
sections.forEach(function (section) {
    section.addEventListener("click", function () {
        sections.forEach(function (section) {
            section.classList.remove("current");
        });
        this.classList.add("current");
        rangeSlider.value = this.getAttribute("data-label");
    });
});
```

```css
#customProgress {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent;
}

.step {
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.step::after {
    content: attr(data-label);
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    right: -0.25em;
}

.step ~ .current,
.step.current {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>what I have achieved</h1>
<div id="customProgress"></div>
<div id="progress" style="width: 100%;">
    <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="opacity: 0.1; width: 100%; height: 50px;" />
</div>
```